# Upstart or Systemd

Tags: upstart, systemd

So I'm confused. I'm getting a lot of mixed information via Google. As of today, what is Ubuntu using going forward? Is Ubuntu choosing to use and support Upstart, or are they using Systemd?

I would like to get multiple responses if that's ok so I can statistically have a better chance of filtering through the opinions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

They will support Upstart for as long as 14.04 is supported (until 2019), but systemd is the future, from 15.04 onwards. As of today: Upstart is used on the following supported releases:

- 10.04
- 12.04
- 14.04
- 14.10

[15.04 is slated to use systemd](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/core-1411-systemd-migration) (and [the development builds](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1427654) have [made the switch](http://lwn.net/Articles/636350/) already). Ubuntu Touch, however, will continue to use [Upstart in 15.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-touch-meta/+bug/1428026).

Comment: Do you have anything official from Ubuntu that I can read on this? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Atomiklan [this blueprint for systemd migration](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/core-1411-systemd-migration) has 15.04 as its release goal. I'll look for more documents.

Comment: @Atomiklan - http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316

Comment: FWIW systemd seems to work well in Fedora, but I anticipate some bumps as Debian / Ubuntu adopts it. Hope they will be minor.