# How to properly setup runit on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, runit

I've successfully installed runit via apt-get (at least I got no errors)

```
Setting up runit (2.1.2-9.2ubuntu1) ...
```

However, it seems runit isn't running itself, so to speak. Following command doesn't show anything.

```
ps -ef | grep runsvdir
```

I was able to run runsvdir manually on `/etc/service` and it seems to work because after that inside my services `supervise` folder appeared. But if I try to run

```
sudo sv status my-service
```

I receive

> fail: my-service: runsv not running

---

I use runit to manage ruby on rails and sidekiq processes. Servers are Digital Ocean droplets. I have one server using Ubuntu 16.04 (which doesn't have this problem) and Ubuntu 18.04 (which have).

The first error I got after provisioning and deploy was actually

> unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist

I am wondering if these issues connected?

1. [Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused: Errors were encountered while processing: runit](https://askubuntu.com/q/654951)
2. [Will Ubuntu 18.04 LTS still support Upstart or do we have to change to systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1024120)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The runit package does not provide a systemd unit file out of the box. But there is a special package that provides it: **runit-systemd**.

Just install this package and runit will do its job.

```
sudo apt install runit-systemd
```

Comment: need a `sudo` to `apt install`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't test your solution right now but thanks for the answer! I think it will come handy later :)